# Modify code to save as jpeg

Tags: c#, bitmap, jpeg

I have the code below, and I'd like it to make it save as jpeg file format, instead of bmp.

```
Bitmap current = (Bitmap)_latestFrame.Clone();
        using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog())
        {
            sfd.Filter = "*.bmp|*.bmp";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                current.Save(sfd.FileName);
            }
        }

        current.Dispose();
    }
```

Do you have any idea on what I should change to make it? I tried using Image.Format, but that didn't work.

Comment: Microsoft documents this well, with examples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Have you tried using simply `.jpg` as file extension?

Answer (score 3):

To save a `BitMap` object as a JPG just specify the `ImageFormat` in the save method

```
currentSave(sdf.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Ideally though you would base this off of the extension chosen by the user.  Something like the following

```
sfd.Filter = "*.bmp|*.jpg:
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
  if (sfd.FileName.EndsWith("jpg")) {
    current.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
  } else { 
    current.Save(sfd.FileName);
  }
}
```